# Pandas Time Series Conversion and Formatting

Tags: pandas, time-series

How do I convert a string in this format to a Pandas timestamp?

00:55:02:285

hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds

I have a dataframe already with several columns in this format.
Pandas don't seem to recognize this format as a timestamp when I use any of the conversion functions, e.g.. to_datetime()

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need parameter `format` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'times':['00:55:02:285','00:55:02:285']})
print (df)
          times
0  00:55:02:285
1  00:55:02:285

print (pd.to_datetime(df.times, format='%H:%M:%S:%f'))
0   1900-01-01 00:55:02.285
1   1900-01-01 00:55:02.285
Name: times, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```